# how can i run 2 thread per core , i have 8 core and 16 threads on ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I have an Intel i7 10700k with 8 cores and 16 threads. On Ubuntu, I see only 1 thread per core. I think there are 2 threads per core. How I can solve this problem?

This is the output of `lscpu`:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          8
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              8
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           165
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700K CPU @ 3.80GHz
Stepping:                        5
CPU MHz:                         3792.008
BogoMIPS:                        7584.01
Hypervisor vendor:               KVM
Virtualization type:             full
L1d cache:                       256 KiB
L1i cache:                       256 KiB
L2 cache:                        2 MiB
L3 cache:                        128 MiB
```

Comment: Is SMP (also called HyperThreading) enabled in your UEFI? 

Comment: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/199335/intel-core-i710700k-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-10-ghz/specifications.html -> Indeed 8 cores, 16 threads. That, however, doesn't mean all software can take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not think all applications can take advantage of too many cores CPUs. You just don't have 2 threads by cores. *looking on your description*, I guess here your motherboard is limited on that so additional threads are ignored. *I had a machine with that same type of limitation few years ago*

Most of them just let the operating system manage that, *depending on hardware & bios setup of course*.

You can still optimize your runs on software-side

If you are sure, there is no setup/hardware issues, use taskset or similar tool.

You can "force" applications to run on a dedicated pool of cores using **taskset**

example :

```
 taskset -cp 4-8 firefox
```

Of course if the application uses only one core/thread, only the first one of the pool you defined is used by that application.